# Will Unity Framework Remove cookies from Context in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an application that have unity framework for dependency injection so my Account Controller is following and that contain Login Action

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public AccountController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string message = "";
            var user = userService.UserExists(model, out message);
            
            if (user != null)
            {
                CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();

                serializeModel.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(user.Id);
                serializeModel.EmailId = user.EmailId;
                serializeModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                serializeModel.LastName = user.LastName;
                serializeModel.role = user.Role;

                string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializeModel,Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                    });
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                         1,
                        user.EmailId,
                         DateTime.Now,
                         model.RememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) : DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                         model.RememberMe ? true : false,
                         userData);
                
                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                faCookie.Expires = model.RememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) : DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);                    
                Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);                    
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                    
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username and/or password");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

.In login action I'm doing following

1. Checking User Is Existed Or Not if existed then adding FormsAuthentication Cookie .
   but when I using IUserService (Interface for DI ) then cookie is deleted when redirect to another action .
2. But if I remove DI from controller then Cookie is persisted .

whats wrong I'm finding answer from couple of days .
please give me solution I want DI and Cookie Both .

Comment: You might want to check how the IUserService registered? i.e per request? per thread? per container etc. Try to change the settings and go from there. Also which code does the cookie persistence?

Comment: thanks for reply actually if i remove " var user = userService.UserExists(model, out message); " this statement then cookies get persisted even i'm not removing IUserService From Controllers Constructor that is public AccountController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }